# Is sharepoint the best or necessary for intranets?

Tags: sharepoint, intranet

Our company is looking at implementing an intranet,

The current one is based on Sharepoint 2007, and is awful.

I'm interested in knowing what alternatives there are to Sharepoint for intranets? The way it is used in the company is just like a standard website with news items, links to information,  document management etc. I'd much rather use a decent CMS such as Umbraco if we were to have a new intranet but unsure as to what we may be missing out on if we ditch sharepoint- 
document management perhaps?
windows pass through authentication?

should we stick with sharepoint?

Answer (score 0):

First off product recommendations are OT on ServerFault, but.. 
Here’s the but; I have just been in your predicament. I have been trialing SP2010 and Umbaco for our Intranet. I needed something that would take the onious out of IT to manage the content. The users needed to be able to do this. Every product I tried I went back to SharePoint 2010.

My reasons;

1. AD Authentication
2. Document Management and Auditing
3. Self Service
4. it looks like  office so users will use it!

Comment: Add: Sp2007 wa awfull, 2010 is a lot better and usable - lets hoüpe the next vsion (out for testing soon) is even better. But 2007 to 2010 is a HUGH step.

Comment: Can you elaborate on Self Service? And surely AD/Windows authentication can be written into any site anyway? - Out of interest did you end up with sharepoint alone or combined with umbraco?

Comment: @raklos we ended up just using SharePoint for Internal. Umbraco for external site. Self Sevice, users/deparments can manage there own pages and not the IT deparment. As it looks like office we found they liked it more than the Umbraco editor.